# Four petals rosette

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

A straight line segment of length 2a moves on the plane keeping its end A and B on the axes of rectangular coordinate system. We construct a prependicular OM from the origin of coordinates M€AB
Write the equation of geometrical locus of point M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve the problem by taking a look at the upper right. 
I would make you a drawing but it's better if you do it on your own. So I will explain to you step by step.

Let's call $\theta$ the angle between the $x$ axis and the $OM$ segment ($\theta=B\widehat{O}M$). Then you have that $O\widehat{A}M$ is equal to $\theta$ too and $O\widehat{A}M$ is equall to $\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$.

Therefore $OB=AB \cdot \cos(\theta)$ and $OA=AB \cdot \sin(\theta)$ because of simple trigonometric relations. 
Finally you know that the area is given by basis times height over 2.
$$Area=\frac{AB\cdot OM}{2}=\frac{OA\cdot OB}{2} $$
Finally just use the fact that $AB=2a$ and you get:
$$OM=\frac{2a \cos(\theta)2a\sin(\theta)}{2a}=2a\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)=a\sin(2\theta)$$
The radius depends on $\theta$. The geometrical locus of point $M$ in vectorial form is:
$$\vec{M}=a\begin{pmatrix}\sin(2\theta)\cos(\theta) \\ \sin(2\theta)\sin(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$$
If you draw it you get a 4-petals rose.